# Расстояния до нуля

Tags: python, алгоритм

Задан массив a0,a1,…,an−1. Для каждого элемента найдите расстояние от него до ближайшего нуля. Гарантируется, что в массиве встречается ноль хотя бы один раз.

Входные данные
В первой строке входных данных содержится целое число n (1≤n≤2⋅10^5) — длина массива a. Вторая строка содержит элементы массива, записанные через пробел (−10^9≤ai≤10^9).

Выходные данные
Выведите последовательность d0,d1,…,dn−1. Значение di должно быть равно расстоянию от элемента в позиции i до ближайшего элемента, равного нулю.

Примеры

```
входные данные

9
2 1 0 3 0 0 3 2 4

выходные данные
2 1 0 1 0 0 1 2 3 

входные данные

5
0 1 2 3 4

выходные данные
0 1 2 3 4 

входные данные
7
5 6 0 1 -2 3 4
выходные данные
2 1 0 1 2 3 4
```

Код:

```
n=int(input())
a=list(map(int, input().split()))
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i]!=0:
        b=[list(reversed(a[:i + 1])), a[i:]]
        left=b[0].index(0) if 0 in b[0] else len(a)
        right=b[1].index(0) if 0 in b[1] else len(a)
        a[i]=min(left,right)
print(*a)
```

Данный код не проходит по времени на 39 тесте. Как его ускорить? Или может быть он неправильный?

Comment: У вас в примерах входные данные длиннее, чем выходные - а по условию должны быть одинаковы...

Comment: @Harry там форматирование было кривое

Comment: А как это исправить?

Comment: переменная n дана, чтобы не использовать каждый раз len(a). И вы создаете n списков, без которых можно обойтись.

Answer (score 5):

Как обычно, ощущение, что у вас O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Увы, я не знаю python, но если вас натолкнет на мысли решение на C++...

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> d(n), zeros;

    int l = 2000000;
    zeros.push_back(-1);
    for(int v, i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cin >> v;
        if (v == 0)
        {
            zeros.push_back(i);
            l = 0;
        }
        d[i] = l++;
    }

    for(int i = 1; i < zeros.size(); ++i)
    {
        int b = zeros[i-1];
        int e = zeros[i];
        for(int j = e-1; j > b; --j)
        {
            if (d[j] > e-j) d[j] = e-j; else break;
        }
    }
    for(int x: d) cout << x << " "; cout << endl;
}
```

Смысл примерно - сначала читаем и отмечаем все нули и вправо от нуля пишем расстояние от последнего считанного нуля.

Потом берем и идем от найденных нулей влево - пока расстояние меньше уже записанного...

Самые левые элементы заполняем фейковым значением, заведопо превосходящим n.

Comment: Лично я бы делал в 1 проход, используя факт, что ровно половина раности уходит к левому 0, остальное в правому. Главное концы не потерять. Для генерации ответа достаточно знать только позицию предыдущего 0.

Comment: @pavel Ну все равно ведь - достигнув правого 0, идти надо будет влево, нет?

Comment: А зачем? Позицию левого мы знаем, сами числа нас не интересуют. А вывести 1 2 3 4 ... (cur-prev)/2 ... 3 2 1 и так можно)

Comment: @pavel Ну... вообще-то да. Можно и не строить... Только когда я о чем-то таком думал, мне показалось, что код будет существенно объемнее...

Answer (score 3):

я бы сделал так:

```
import numpy as np

def func(lst):
    lst=np.array(list(map(int, lst.split())))
    zeros = np.where(lst==0)[0]
    for i in np.nonzero(lst)[0]:
        lst[i] = min(np.abs(i-zeros))
    return lst.tolist()
```

Тесты:

```
print(func('0 2 1 0 3 0 0 3 2 4'))
print(func('2 1 0 3 0 0 3 2 4'))
print(func('0 1 2 3 4'))
print(func('5 6 0 1 -2 3 4'))
```

Вывод:

```
[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3]
[2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: No module named 'numpy' пишет...

Comment: Значит, его нужно установить. `pip install numpy`, например

Comment: invalid syntax пишет

Comment: Учитель сказала сделать без numpy и без enumerate, но, к сожалению, я не могу понять, как это сделать...

Answer (score 0):

```
n= int(input())
a = input().split()
fwd = []
bwd = []
for i in range(n):
    a[i] = int(a[i])
    if a[i] == 0:
        fwd.append(i)
bwd = fwd[::-1]
for i in range(n):
    bw = min(abs(i - fwd[0]), abs(i - bwd[-1]))
    if a[i] == 0:
        if len(fwd) > 1:
            fwd.pop(0)
            bwd.pop()
    a[i] = bw
    print(bw, end=" ")
```

Comment: Саша Новожилов, на 19 тесте, к сожалению, не проходит

Answer (score 0):

Верный код такой, но выполняется больше 3 сек.:

```
n = 9
a = [2, 5, 0, 7, 2, 3, 0, 6, 0]
a_rev = list(reversed(a))

fwd = []
bwd = []
for i in range(n):
    if a[i] == 0:
        fwd.append(i)
    if a_rev[i] == 0:
        bwd.append(i)
for i in range(n):
    bw = abs(i - fwd[0])
    fw = abs(i - bwd[0])
    if a[i] == 0:
        if len(fwd) > 1:
            fwd.pop(0)
    if a_rev[i] == 0:
        if len(bwd) > 1:
            bwd.pop(0)
    a[i] = bw
    a_rev[i] = fw
a_rev = a_rev[::-1]
rezult_dist = [min(f, b) for f, b in zip(a, a_rev)]
result_list_string = [str(i) for i in rezult_dist]
result_string = ' '.join(result_list_string)
# вывод в терминал
print(result_string)
```

Вывод:

> 2 1 0 1 2 1 0 1 0

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Время выполнения : 2.09s

```
    def distance_one_way(house_list):
            last_null = -1
            one_way_list = [0] * n
            for null_number in range(0, n):
                if house_list[null_number] == '0':
                    for house_number in range(last_null + 1, null_number):
                        one_way_list[house_number] = abs(house_number-null_number)
                    last_null = int(null_number)
            if last_null < n:
                for house_number in range(last_null+1, n):
                    one_way_list[house_number] = float("inf")
            return one_way_list
        
        
        def distance_two_way(house_list):
            forward = distance_one_way(house_list)
            backward = distance_one_way(house_list[::-1])
            final_list = [min(forward_dist, back_dist)
                          for forward_dist, back_dist in zip(forward, backward[::-1])]
            final_list = [str(distance) for distance in final_list]
            return final_list
        
        
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            n = int(input())
            house_list = list(input().split())
            print(" ".join(distance_two_way(house_list)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваше решение работает за квадратичное время, так как для каждой позиции вы выполняете линейный поиск ближайшего нуля слева и справа. Ваш вариант можно поправить сравнительно легко, но это уже сделано несколько раз так что ...

... решение из разряда ненормального программирования. Задачу можно решить за линейное время (что не новость) и в памяти пропорциональной логарифму расстояния между соседними нулями (это новинка).

Чтобы удовлетворить жестким ограничениям по памяти пришлось отказаться от чтения входных данных через `input()` (сразу линейная память!). Чтение сделано посимвольно, счётчик чисел пропускается, сами числа не анализируются целиком - проверяется лишь только первый символ. В памяти хранится только расстояние до последнего встреченного нуля. В печати пришлось отказаться от `print(*...)` чтобы сократить требования к памяти:

```
import sys


# пропускает пробелы
# возвращает первый непробел или пустую строку если файл кончился
def skip_spaces():
    c = ' '
    # выйти если файл кончился или прочитан нeпробел
    while c.isspace():
        c = sys.stdin.read(1)
    return c


# пропускает непробелы
# возвращает первый пробел или пустую строку если файл кончился
def skip_nonspaces():
    c = '_' # или любой непробел
    # выйти если файл кончился или прочитан пробел
    while c != '' and not c.isspace():
        c = sys.stdin.read(1)
    return c


# читает числа из файла, выдаёт флаги вида "это ноль"
# по числу прочитанных чисел
def read_zeros():
    while True:
        # пропустить пробельные символы
        c = skip_spaces()
        if c == '': # признак конца файла
            break

        # ноль - единственное число начинающееся с символа '0'
        yield c == '0'

        # пропустить все символы до пробела или конца файла
        if skip_nonspaces() == '': # признак конца файла
            break


# решает задачу: читает числа, выводит расстояния до ближайшего нуля
def dists():
    first = True
    k = 0 # эта переменная отвечает за логарифмическую память
    for z in read_zeros():
        if z:
            if first:
                yield from range(k, 0, -1) # первый спуск
                first = False
            else:
                h = k // 2
                yield from range(h + 1)            # подъём на холм
                yield from range(k - h - 1, 0, -1) # спуск с холма
            k = 0
        k += 1
    yield from range(k) # последний подъём


def main():
    # пропустить n
    skip_spaces()
    skip_nonspaces()

    first = True
    for d in dists():
        if first:
            first = False
            print(d, end='') # просто число
        else:
            print('', d, end='') # пробел и число
    print()


main()
```