# При выполнении кода ошибка TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python

```
def func():
    lenght = int(input())
    array = list(map(int, input().split()))
    result = []
    result_test = []
    number = 0
    for i in range(lenght):
        if array[i] != 0:
            number += 1
            result_test.append(number)
            if i == lenght -1:
                result.extend(result_test)
        else:
            if len(result) == 0:
                result.extend(result_test[::-1])
                result.extend([0])
                number = 0
                result_test.clear()
            else:
                for i in range(len(result_test)):
                    result.extend(min(result_test[i], result_test[::-1][i]))
                number = 0
                result.extend([0])
                result_test.clear()
    print(' '.join(str(i) for i in result))
func()
```

Задача найти расстояние до ближайшего ноля.
Сначала вводим длину, потом саму строку цифр.
Например 6, потом 1 3 0 1 9 1.
Если ввести такую последовательность, код работает, если ввести два ноля не друг за другом, к примеру 1 1 1 0 1 0, то выдаёт ошибку TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable.
Помогите понять в чем дело?

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его галочкой как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: что, если в списке не будет нулей?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1065376/420098

Answer (score 1):

проблема в строке

```
result.extend(min(result_test[i], result_test[::-1][i]))
```

а именно в том что

```
min(result_test[i], result_test[::-1][i])
```

выдает вам одно число, а вы далее пытаетесь добавить его в `result` с помощью `extend`. Замените `extend` на `append`

Comment: Спасибо, добрый человек!)