# Оптимизация программы по поиску пути до ближайшего нуля Python

Tags: python

Прохожу курсы по Python, стоит задача по поиску расстояния до ближайшего нуля.

Вводные данные (пример):

```
5 # кол-во элементов
0 1 4 9 0
```

А должно быть:

```
0 1 2 1 0
```

Задачу я решил, но при прохождении тестов, где программу нагружают по-максимум, она валится из-за ограничении памяти. Т.е. надо как-то оптимизировать мой код, но как - ума не приложу.

```
street = int(input())
land_number = input().split()

f = []

zero_number = [k for k, v in enumerate(land_number) if v == '0']

for i in range(len(zero_number)):
    left = list(reversed(range(0, len(land_number[:zero_number[i]:]) + 1)))
    right = list((range(1, len(land_number[zero_number[i] + 1:]) + 1)))
    f.append(left + right)
print(*map(min, zip(*f)))
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Расстояния до нуля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1065256/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%be-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f)

Comment: А какие ограничения в задаче? И можно ли получить доступ к тестирующей системе? А вообще, у вас алгоритм квадратный как по времени, так и по памяти, поэтому не думаю, что его можно ускорить без значительных изменений. Например, можно для i-того нуля минимизировать не все расстояния, а только те, которые находятся между (i-1)-ым и (i+1)-ым нулями. Но тогда всю внутренность вашего цикла нужно полностью менять, а ведь это и есть основа вашего алгоритма.

Comment: Но чтобы оптимизировать именно по памяти рекомендую вместо `f = []` использовать `ans = [street] * street`, вместо `f.append()` использовать `ans = list(map(min, zip(ans, left+right)))` и соответственно в конце выводить с помощью `print(*ans)`. Таким образом, память получается линейная, хоть скорость и оставляет желать лучшего

Comment: Спасибо. Все как вы сказали - по памяти стало ок, но программа возникли проблемы со скоростью)
К сожалению, к тест-системе доступ только у студентов курса (

Comment: В итоге код пришлось переписать полностью и тесты пролезли. Спасибо EzikBro!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот за 2 прохода по списку туда-обратно:

```
data = [0, 1, 4, 9, 0]
res = [0] * len(data)

i_zero_first = i_zero_last = data.index(0)
for i in range(i_zero_first, len(data)):
    if data[i] != 0:
        res[i] = res[i-1] + 1
    else:
        i_zero_last = i

for i in range(i_zero_last, i_zero_first, -1):
    res[i] = 0 if data[i] == 0 else min(res[i], res[i+1] + 1)

for i in range(i_zero_first-1, -1, -1):
    res[i] = res[i+1] + 1

print(res)
```

В принципе, тут даже второй список не нужен. Если входные данные больше не представляют ценности, то можно проводить все манипуляции прямо в над исходным списком.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше решение) воспользуюсь, если свой не смогу исправить (
пока хотелось как-то оптимизировать свой код, если это возможно